# Fmncg and fminunc working explanation in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, octave

It is clear that fmincg and fminunc functions give the optimum theta values using the cost function which provides the cost value (JVal) and the gradients with respect to theta.
But how does the code for these functions work? I want to know the internal functioning of these functions. This is with respect to Andrew Ng Machine Learning Course on Coursera.

```
[nn_params, cost] = fmincg(costFunction, initial_nn_params, options);
```

This is the code for fmincg function. It takes the cost function as input which is as follows:

```
costFunction = @(p) nnCostFunction(p, ...
                                   input_layer_size, ...
                                   hidden_layer_size, ...
                                   num_labels, X, y, lambda);
```

Hence fmincg returns the nn_params which is an unrolled vector, it can be converted to theta values as:

```
Theta1 = reshape(nn_params(1:hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size + 1)), ...
                 hidden_layer_size, (input_layer_size + 1));

Theta2 = reshape(nn_params((1 + (hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size + 1))):end), ...
                 num_labels, (hidden_layer_size + 1));
```

Comment: For the next time, please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code blocks (done it for you here).

Comment: Thanks for the edit @desertnaut. Will surely take care next time.

Comment: fmincg isn't part of GNU Octave or octave-forge. It's part of andrews course. You really should provide a link to it

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Andy. While learning logistic regression in the machine learning course on coursera, the documentation mentioned- "you will use an Octave/-MATLAB built-in function called fminunc." Hence I felt the need to understand the functioning behind.